# SQLite Database Android - INSERT method

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, insert

I'm having problems with inserting values into my Android SQLite database's table. I've already tried adapting a few tutorial examples but to no avail. Could someone take a look at my code to point out what should I change to make it work? Here is code of my class:

```
public class Baza extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
SQLiteDatabase db;
static final String dbName ="MyDb";
static final int dbVersion = 1;

// tabela przepisy
static final String TabName = "Przepisy";
static final String TabCol1 = "id";
static final String TabCol2 = "Nazwa";
static final String TabCol3 = "Kategoria";

static final String dbCreate = "CREATE TABLE" + TabName + "(" + 
    TabCol1+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+
    TabCol2+ " TEXT, " +
    TabCol3+ " TEXT)";

public Baza(Context context) {
    super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(dbCreate);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TabName);
}

public boolean insert(String name, String cat)
{
    db = super.getWritableDatabase();
     ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

       cv.put(TabCol2, name);
       cv.put(TabCol3, cat);

       long isAdded = db.insert(TabName, null, cv);
       if (isAdded == -1)       return false;
       else return true;
}
}
```

I'd be grateful for any help.

Logcat error:

```
 I/Process(1289): Sending signal. PID: 1289 SIG: 9
 D/AndroidRuntime(1318): Shutting down VM
 W/dalvikvm(1318): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1318): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 E/AndroidRuntime(1318): java.lang.NullPointerException
 E/AndroidRuntime(1318):    at com.example.mojabaza.Baza.insert(Baza.java:60)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1318):    at com.example.mojabaza.Mojabaza$2.onClick(Mojabaza.java:45)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1318):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1318):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1318):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1318):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1318):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1318):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1318):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1318):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1318):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1318):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 E/AndroidRuntime(1318):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post your stack trace? That could help a bit.

Comment: show us how you create Baza instance and use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a space and I am not sure `AUTO INCREMENT` is two words:

```
"CREATE TABLE" + TabName + "(" + 
    TabCol1+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO INCREMENT, "+
```

Use:

```
//    Added: v
"CREATE TABLE " + TabName + "(" + 
    TabCol1+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+ // autoincrement is implied as well as `not null`
```

Depending on the error you may need to set `dbVersion` equal to 2 build this new schema.

Comment: Thank you for help and answer. I changed code, but it still doesn't work. Error occures when I invoke insert(String, String) method in line: db = super.getWritableDatabase();

Comment: Click ["edit"](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14187269/edit) under your question to post the LogCat errors so we can see what is happening. (Please notify me with a comment when you do.)

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException   at com.example.mojabaza.Baza.insert(Baza.java:60)`  Ok, in `Baza.java` is this line 60: `long isAdded = db.insert(TabName, null, cv);`?

Comment: Hi, I deleted AUTO INCREMENT as you said and it works! Nevertheless, cells in TabCol1 (id_) are auto incremented :) Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Comment: You're welcome. Please click the check mark to accept this answer as the solution. And good luck!

Comment: Well, I've got another problem :/ In other Activity I want to get access to my database from previous Activity but I don't know how to do it. Could someone help me?

Comment: It is unlikely that anyone (aside from me) will find this comment. So you should ask a new question, be sure to include a brief description, the relevant code, and the LogCat errors. But first please click the check mark to accept the answer as the solution to the question above.

Comment: "But first please click the check mark to accept the answer as the solution to the question above: - how to do it? Where is that check mark?

Comment: On the left side of the code in my answer, there should be an outline of a green check mark. This might help: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/188646)

Comment: Done :) I would be grateful if you'd look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221679/sqlite-database-android-using-opening-and-querries-in-database-in-other-activ :)