# SQLite Database Android - using, opening and queries in database in other Activities

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-activity

I'm having problems with open created database in other Activity than was created. Actually I don't know how to do it. Insert and query methods in Activity where database was created, works good. But I want to open that database in other Activity and use my queries. I read about `openOrCreateDatabase()` method but I don't know how to use it. I think I should use `createDataBase()` method in my class `Baza` but (as in case `openOrCreateDatabase()`) I don't know how to use it. Could someone help me with solving my problems?

Baza code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Baza extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


SQLiteDatabase db;
static final String dbName ="cookBook.db";
static final int dbVersion = 2;

// tabela przepisy
static final String TabelaPrzepisyNazwa = "Przepisy";
static final String TabPrzepisyCol1 = "_id";            static final int    TabPrzepisyCol1Number = 1;
static final String TabPrzepisyCol2 = "Nazwa";          static final int    TabPrzepisyCol2Number = 2;  
static final String TabPrzepisyCol3 = "Kategoria";      static final int    TabPrzepisyCol3Number = 3;
static final String TabPrzepisyCol4 = "Cena";           static final int    TabPrzepisyCol4Number = 4;
static final String TabPrzepisyCol5 = "Przygotowanie";  static final int    TabPrzepisyCol5Number = 5;
static final String TabPrzepisyCol6 = "Kalorycznosc";   static final int    TabPrzepisyCol6Number = 6;
static final String TabPrzepisyCol7 = "Czas";           static final int    TabPrzepisyCol7Number = 7;




static final String TabelaPrzepSkladNazwa = "PrzepSklad";
static final String TabPrzepSkladCol1 = "_id";          static final int    TabPrzepSkladCol1Number = 1;
static final String TabPrzepskladCol2 = "Nazwa";        static final int    TabPrzepskladCol2Number = 2;    
static final String TabPrzepskladCol3 = "Ilosc";        static final int    TabPrzepskladCol3Number = 3;
static final String TabPrzepskladCol4 = "IdDania";      static final int    TabPrzepskladCol4Number = 4;


static final String przepisyTabCreate = "CREATE TABLE " + TabelaPrzepisyNazwa + "(" + 
        TabPrzepisyCol1+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        TabPrzepisyCol2+ " TEXT, " + 
        TabPrzepisyCol3+ " TEXT, " +
        TabPrzepisyCol4+ " INTEGER, " +
        TabPrzepisyCol5+ " TEXT, " +
        TabPrzepisyCol6+ " INTEGER, " +
        TabPrzepisyCol7+ " INTEGER)";


static final String przepSkladTabCreate = "CREATE TABLE " + TabelaPrzepSkladNazwa + "(" + 
        TabPrzepSkladCol1+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
        TabPrzepskladCol2+ " TEXT, " +
        TabPrzepskladCol3+ " INTEGER, " +
        TabPrzepskladCol4+ " INTEGER)"; 




public Baza(Context context) {

    super(context, dbName, null, dbVersion);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(przepisyTabCreate);
    db.execSQL(przepSkladTabCreate);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TabelaPrzepisyNazwa);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TabelaPrzepSkladNazwa);

}

public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

public long dodajDanieDoBazy(String name, String cat, int price, String opis, int kcal, int czas)
{
    db = super.getWritableDatabase();
     ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

       cv.put(TabPrzepisyCol2, name);
       cv.put(TabPrzepisyCol3, cat);
       cv.put(TabPrzepisyCol4, price);
       cv.put(TabPrzepisyCol5, opis);
       cv.put(TabPrzepisyCol6, kcal);
       cv.put(TabPrzepisyCol7, czas);

       return (db.insert(TabelaPrzepisyNazwa, null, cv));
}


public long dodajSkladnikDoDania(String nazwaSkladnika, int iloscSkladnika, int idDania)
{
    db = super.getWritableDatabase();
     ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

       cv.put(TabPrzepskladCol2, nazwaSkladnika);
       cv.put(TabPrzepskladCol3, iloscSkladnika);
       cv.put(TabPrzepskladCol4, idDania);

       return (db.insert(TabelaPrzepSkladNazwa, null, cv));     
}

public ArrayList<String> znajdzIdOpisDania (String phraze)
{
    ArrayList<String> ListaDoZwrotu = new ArrayList<String>();
    db=super.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] ktoreKolumny = {TabPrzepisyCol1, TabPrzepisyCol2, TabPrzepisyCol4, TabPrzepisyCol5, TabPrzepisyCol6, TabPrzepisyCol7};
    String WHERE = TabPrzepisyCol2 + " =?";
    String[] wyszukiwanie = {phraze};
    Cursor c = db.query(TabelaPrzepisyNazwa,ktoreKolumny,WHERE, wyszukiwanie, null, null, null);
    try {
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            String temp = new String();
            temp = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TabPrzepisyCol1));
            ListaDoZwrotu.add(temp);
            temp = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TabPrzepisyCol2));
            ListaDoZwrotu.add(temp);
            temp = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TabPrzepisyCol4));
            ListaDoZwrotu.add(temp);
            temp = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TabPrzepisyCol5));
            ListaDoZwrotu.add(temp);
            temp = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TabPrzepisyCol6));
            ListaDoZwrotu.add(temp);
            temp = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TabPrzepisyCol7));
            ListaDoZwrotu.add(temp);
            return ListaDoZwrotu;
        }
        else return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)     {
        return null;
    }
}



public ArrayList<String> znajdzSkladnikiDania (String phraze)
{
    ArrayList<String> listaSkladnikow = new ArrayList<String>();
    db=super.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] ktoreKolumny = {TabPrzepskladCol2, TabPrzepskladCol3};
    String WHERE = TabPrzepskladCol4 + " =?";
    String[] wyszukiwanie = {phraze};
    Cursor c = db.query(TabelaPrzepSkladNazwa,ktoreKolumny,WHERE, wyszukiwanie, null, null, null);
    try {
        if(c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String temp = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TabPrzepskladCol2)) + " - " 
                        + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TabPrzepskladCol3));
                listaSkladnikow.add(temp);
                } while (c.moveToNext());

            return listaSkladnikow;
        }
        else return null;
        }
        catch (Exception e)     {
            return null;
        }
}

public ArrayList<String> find(String phraze)
{
    ArrayList<String> listaWyszukan = new ArrayList<String>();
    db=super.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] ktoreKolumny = {TabPrzepisyCol2};
    String WHERE = TabPrzepisyCol3 + " =?";
    String[] wyszukiwanie = {phraze};
    Cursor c = db.query(TabelaPrzepisyNazwa,ktoreKolumny,WHERE, wyszukiwanie, null, null, null);
    //String zwr = Integer.toString(c.getCount());
    try {
    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
        String temp = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TabPrzepisyCol2));
        listaWyszukan.add(temp);
        } while (c.moveToNext());

        return listaWyszukan;
    }
    else return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)     {
        return null;
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> findByPrice(int price)
{
    ArrayList<String> listaWyszukan = new ArrayList<String>();
    db=super.getReadableDatabase();
    String[] ktoreKolumny = {TabPrzepisyCol2};
    String WHERE = TabPrzepisyCol4 + " <?";
    String[] wyszukiwanie = {Integer.toString(price)};
    Cursor c = db.query(TabelaPrzepisyNazwa,ktoreKolumny,WHERE, wyszukiwanie, null, null, null);
    try {
    if(c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
        String temp = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(TabPrzepisyCol2));
        listaWyszukan.add(temp);
        } while (c.moveToNext());

        return listaWyszukan;
    }
    else return null;
    }
    catch (Exception e)     {
        return null;
    }
}


public void deleteAll()
{
     db=super.getReadableDatabase();
     db.delete(TabelaPrzepisyNazwa, null, null);
     db.delete(TabelaPrzepSkladNazwa, null, null);

}
}
```

First Activity code:

```
bazaDanych = new Baza(getApplicationContext());
bazaDanych.deleteAll();
bazaDanych.dodajDanieDoBazy("Ex 1", "Cat1", 4, "description", 280, 40);
```

Second Activity code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wyszukiwarkaprzepisow);

    tytul = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    blabla = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    ustawCzcionke(tytul);

    Baza bazaDanych = new Baza(getApplicationContext());
String wyborSpinnerDania = "3";
ArrayList<String> szukaneDanie = new ArrayList<String>();
szukaneDanie = bazaDanych.znajdzIdOpisDania(wyborSpinnerDania);
blabla.setText(szukaneDanie.get(0));
//blabla.setText("exa");

}
```

Logcat errors when i switch to Activity where i want to get acces my db:

```
W/dalvikvm(14576): threadid=1: thread    Exiting with uncaught    Exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576): FATAL    EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(14576): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.kajsmig.cookBook/com.kajsmig.cookBook.WyszukiwarkaPrzepisowActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1872)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1692)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:656)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at com.kajsmig.cookBook.ExtendActivity.przlaczAktywnosc(ExtendActivity.java:90)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at com.kajsmig.cookBook.PrzepisyActivity.onGesturePerformed(PrzepisyActivity.java:293)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.fireOnGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView.java:728)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at android.gesture.GestureOverlayView.access$400(GestureOverlayView.java:55)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at android.gesture.GestureOverlayView$FadeOutRunnable.run(GestureOverlayView.java:743)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at com.kajsmig.cookBook.WyszukiwarkaPrzepisowActivity.onCreate(WyszukiwarkaPrzepisowActivity.java:50)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1072)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1836)
E/AndroidRuntime(14576):    ... 19 more
```

What should I change, add or delete?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at com.kajsmig.cookBook.WyszukiwarkaPrzepisowActivity.onCreate(WyszukiwarkaPrzepisowActivity.java:50)` What is line 50 in `WyszukiwarkaPrzepisowActivity`? Please post the relevant code from your this Activity's `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Baza bazaDanych = new Baza(getApplicationContext());
    String wyborSpinnerDania = "3";
    ArrayList<String> szukaneDanie = new ArrayList<String>();
    szukaneDanie = bazaDanych.znajdzIdOpisDania(wyborSpinnerDania);
    blabla.setText(szukaneDanie.get(0)); //<-- Line 50


When i comment line 50, App works but ofcourse TextView blabla is not overwritten

Comment: @user1953558 : `blabla.setText` creating problem make sure have initialize `blabla` textview?

Comment: I agree. You either forgot to initialize `blabla` with `blabla = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xxx)` or your current layout does not have a View with the appropriate id.

Comment: Sorry guys, I didn't give whole code. I'll update it.

Comment: I'm trying to use openOrCreateDatabase in OnCreate to try open or create the same database in every moment when I create new Baza object. Or maybe this is wrong idea and I musn't create new Baza object in every Activity where I want to access database?
Anyway, if I have to do this, should I use openOrCreateDatabase in OnCreate?

Answer (score 0):

Create new interface "Defined", like this :

```
import android.provider.BaseColumns;

public interface Stale extends BaseColumns {
public static final String NAZWA_TABELI1 = "konta"; 
public static final String NAZWA_TABELI2 = "notatki"; 
public static final String NAZWA_TABELI3 = "logowania"; 

//TABELA 1 
public static final String INT1 = "id1";
public static final String LOGIN = "login"; 
public static final String HASH = "hash";

// TABELA 2
public static final String INT2 = "id2";
public static final String TYTUL = "tytul";
public static final String TRESC = "tresc";
public static final String KIEDY = "kiedy"; 
public static final String KTO = "kto"; 


// TABELA 3
public static final String INT3 = "id3";
public static final String KTORY = "ktory";
public static final String WANN = "wann";
```

}

After this create new class extends SQLiteOpenHelper. Here is example :

```
public class Bazodanowiec extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String NAZWA_BAZY = "database.db";
    public static final int WERSJA_BAZY = 1;

    public Bazodanowiec(Context kon)
    {
        super(kon, NAZWA_BAZY, null, WERSJA_BAZY );
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase bd)
    {
        bd.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + NAZWA_TABELI1 + " (" + INT1 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + LOGIN + " VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, " + HASH + " VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL);");
        bd.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + NAZWA_TABELI2 + " (" + INT2 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + TYTUL + " VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, " + TRESC + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KIEDY + " TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, " + KTO + " INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(kto) REFERENCES konta(id1));");
        bd.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + NAZWA_TABELI1 + " (" + INT3 + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KTORY + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " + WANN + " TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, FOREIGN KEY(ktory) REFERENCES konta(id1));");
    }


    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NAZWA_TABELI1 + ";");
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NAZWA_TABELI2 + ";");
      db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + NAZWA_TABELI3 + ";");
      onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

You must import static created interface. Try now again

Comment: I see I've got the same structure

Comment: Nah, I didn't changed code, because I've got the same one and i dont see differences :(